# Ethminer from LAN

Tags: parity, ethminer, ropsten

Is it possible to run ethminer from a different pc in my LAN than the one running my Parity ETH client?

I tried with -F http://private.ip:8545 but it seems to be not reacheable.

Thanks!

PS: I'm trying to mine ropsten blocks in order to get some rospten ETH rewards. I tried running locally (in the Parity ETH client PC) but although it seems to be mining after 24hs no ether was granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You will need to set `parity` to listen to your LAN interface for connections instead of `localhost`. Use the `--jsonrpc-interface` parameter and provide your private IP address as the argument. **N.B. The reason why the default for Parity to use `localhost` is for security reasons**: it's *possible* for someone to try to hijack your accounts if outside connections are enabled. Changing the JSON RPC interface allows other computers to issue commands to your Parity client. I think it's good security practice to assume that there are random people on your network due to router firmware being compromised.

For ropsten, I'm guessing the cost (and benefit to an attacker) of a successful hack is low, so you might not worry about it. I would take additional precautions for the main net (such as not keeping any hot wallets connected to that Parity instance).

Comment: Thanks @lungj! I'm aware of the security issues, but it's only for lab purpose.